# discord.py can't get new message with on_message method

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

```
import discord

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.messages = True
intents.message_content = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents, proxy='http://127.0.0.1:10810')


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    print(message.content)
    print(message.channel)


client.run('<token>')
```

i run this code,and there is no new message printed......after i did some research,othere people told i need to deploy my bot with my OAuth2 URL Generator on discord portal,i did that and i can get new message on my own server.but i cant deploy bot to a server that i have no administration with,so how to get new message with a server that i am no administrator with??

Comment: Did you [invite the bot](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/discord.html#inviting-your-bot) into your server? Your bot cannot receive messages from servers that it's not a member of.

Comment: i tried invite the bot to the server,but it required  that i have administration of the server..otherwise i cant set the bot to the server,how to solve this issue?

Comment: Where you don't have admin perms, just ask the owner of the server to invite the bot. However if you are trying to outplay the owner (nuke bot), we can't help you with that. I don't recommend that and I'm strongly against it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to invite the bot to the server if you want to use the bot in it.

Contact the server administrator and send them a bot invite link with required permissions like `send messages` and `read message history`.